# Дана строка, заканчивающаяся точкой преобразовать ее, удалив каждый символ * и повторив каждый символ, отличный от *. Нужно это сделать на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно эту задачу на python сделать сам мучаюсь не знаю даже с чего начать

Comment: Учебные задания принимаются только в том случае, если вы сами пытались его решить. Если вы совсем не знаете с чего начать - загуглите "питон работа со строками".

Answer (score 3):

> сам мучаюсь не знаю даже с чего начать

когда не знаете с чего начать - решайте в лоб

1. пройдитесь по всем символам строки (т.е. по позициям от 0 до `len`)
2. если символ на этой позиции `*` - переходите к следующему
3. если символ на этой позиции не `*` - 2 раза добавляйте его в новую строку
4. в конце присвойте старой строке значение новой строки

Answer (score 2):

https://ideone.com/9B0G1C

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'\*|(.)', r'\1\1', input()))
```

Comment: [регулярки... зачем когда можно и проще без них?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1190180/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b8-%d0%bf/1190206#1190206)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, потому что регулярки я знаю, а питон не очень. Да, у тебя красиво получилось :)

Comment: спасибо..... ;)

Comment: Интересно зачем я поставил сюда минус? Если отредактируте вопрос, то я его сниму

Comment: @Danis, ответ, а не вопрос? Готово, но можно было это сделать самостоятельно.

Comment: Да ответ, ошибся

Answer (score 2):

Раз решать все равно все кинулись, а нормальный питоничный код никто еще не написал...

```
lambda s: ''.join(ch * 2 for ch in s if ch != '*')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def double_symbol_no_stars(string):
    ans = ''
    for i in string:
        if i == '*':
            continue
        else:
            ans += i * 2
    return ans


test = 'Дана строка, заканчивающаяся точкой преобразовать ее, удалив каждый символ * и повторив каждый символ, отличный от *. Нужно это сделать на python.'
print(double_symbol_no_stars(test))
```

Comment: в лоб это конечно хорошо, но можно и по красивее...

Comment: Полагаю, что если у человека возник подобный вопрос, значит он, скорее всего, ещё не знаком с генераторами списков и лямбда выражениями, а значит подобный код для него будет не читаем. Сам думал, что не стоит использовать даже определение функции, но решил, что так будет правильнее и красивее всё таки...

Comment: Если ему эти конструкции не показать, то он 
 их и учить не будет. А так пусть погуглить, будет полезно ;)